# Event triggered multiple times - wagmi - watchAccount

Tags: metamask, walletconnect, wagmi

I've created a Dapp that uses react, web3modal and some functions from wagmi. What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

User clicks button for connecting wallet -> web3modal is displayed -> after he connects his wallet I'll trigger a function.

My issue is that 'accountsChanged' event or watchAccount from wagmi/core will trigger the event multiple times, even with the following code added in useEffect:

```
watchAccount((account) => {
    if (account.isConnected) {
        console.log(account.address)
    }
})
```

The above snippet will log the connected address multiple times. What am I supposed to do in order to have a function triggered only once just after the users wallet is connected?

Thank you!

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid rerun between renders you can use memo https://react.dev/reference/react/memo

or wrap the component in a function using https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo

As well be sure your dApp is not using strict mode at production:
https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode

> Strict Mode enables the following development-only behaviors:
>
> Your components will re-render an extra time to find bugs caused by
> impure rendering. Your components will re-run Effects an extra time to
> find bugs caused by missing Effect cleanup. Your components will be
> checked for usage of deprecated APIs.